# How can we separate string by only its starting characters in PHP

Tags: php, hex, explode, strtok

I am trying to separate a very long string which starting tag is 2424...
This a function where its doing it

```
protected function StartTagCheckAndNeglect($hex)
       {
       try {

        $token = strtok($hex, "2424");

        while ($token !== false) {
            echo "$token<br>";
            $token = strtok("(2424)");
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

$hex has very long hex string...**THE PROBLEM IS** instead of only separting string that start with 2424....it split any thing that start with 2 or 4.
Example : 24246778672552dd455
It gives :4677867,
55,
dd,
55
What i want is 6778672552dd455 in one string until next 2424.Any Better solution would be helpful.

Comment: you can split them, and then loop through the array and put them together, just without id 0

Comment: No, if i will do that the single 2 and 4 will be missed along with starting 2424....i only want 2424 to be missed that are together in start only not single 2 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use `explode()` with 2424 as the delimiter.  You can then check if the first element is empty (so there is nothing before the first 2424) and there are more than 1 elements (using `count()`)...

```
$test = "24246778672552dd4552424a123";

$results = explode("2424", $test);
if ( empty($results[0]) && count($results) > 1 )   {
    //found
    array_shift($results);   // Remove empty element
    print_r($results);
}
```

outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6778672552dd455
    [1] => a123
)
```

The problem with [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) is that it will split the string based on ANY of the characters in your string, so it will split on either 2 or 4 and not 2424.  From the manual...

> **strtok()** splits a string (str) into smaller strings (tokens), with
>   each token being delimited by any character from token.

Comment: This is also the right answer i had tested this one too..Thank You

Comment: Actually this was the right answer so dumb of me :'(

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `preg_split` to have your data split into arrays.

```
$hex = '24246778672552dd45524248763257490823508lale9794382';
$hexarray = preg_split("/(2424)/", $hex);
print_r($hexarray);

// expected result
// Array ( [0] => [1] => 6778672552dd455 [2] => 8763257490823508lale9794382 )
```

Comment: Also, note that according to PHP documentation, explode() is faster if speed is a concern. `$hexarray = explode("2424", $hex);`

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Yes you are right because the length of data was not properly fetch even after doing preg_split which i was thinking was right but explode solved the issue.